# MultiThread stopWatch timer in WinForms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, timer

I want to run timer every 10 miliseconds and update GUI label string. I have create Class TimerController, were i can set up System.Threading.Timer properties.

```
 class TimerControl
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan CurrentElapsedTime { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan TotalElapsedTime { get; private set; }
    public event EventHandler Tick;
    public bool IsTimerRunning { get; private set; }
    public string CurrentElapsedTimeString { get; private set; } = "";
    public TimerCallback TimerAction { get; private set; }
    public object TimerParametr { get; private set; }
    public int DueTime { get; private set; }
    public int Period { get; private set; }

    public TimerControl(TimerCallback timerAction, object state, int dueTime, int period)
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        CurrentElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TotalElapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        TimerAction = timerAction;
        TimerParametr = state;
        DueTime = dueTime;
        Period = period;
        
    }
        
    public void StartTimer()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        TotalElapsedTime = CurrentElapsedTime;
        IsTimerRunning = true;
        if (_timer == null)
            _timer = new Timer(TimerAction, TimerParametr, DueTime, Period);
        else
            _timer.Change(DueTime, Period);
    }
    public void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Change(0, -1);
    }
```

I create TimerControl object in MainForm.cs and I need to create function, that will be triggered by a timer. This function should update GUI time label. But in this function i dont habe access to GUI. How to fix it?

```
TimerControl timerControl = new TimerControl(StopWatchTimer,null, 0, 10); 
    
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    

    private void btn_timerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(btn_timerStart.Text == "Старт")
        {
            timerControl.StartTimer();
            btn_timerStart.Text = "Стоп";
        }
        else
        {
            timerControl.StopTimer();
            btn_timerStart.Text = "Старт";
            
            
        }
    }
    // Callback timer funnction
    private static void StopWatchTimer(object label)
    {
       
        //labelTime =       // labelTime doesnt exist in current context
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you don't have access because you wrote a static method: `private static void StopWatchTimer`, and they cannot access instance variables. Why did you make it static? remove it and you should have access. But BEWARE! since you are not using the WinForms.Timer class, your callback action will be executed on a different thread, and if you try to modify GUI elements in there you will get an exception

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) component?

Comment: `I want to run timer every 10 miliseconds` Regardless of anything else, this is way too short a period to be using when updating the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

I did it like that, everything works fine.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

    TimerControl timerControl;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerControl = new TimerControl(StopWatchTimer, l_timer, 0, 10);
    }

    private void btn_timerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(btn_timerStart.Text == "Старт")
        {
            timerControl.StartTimer();
            btn_timerStart.Text = "Стоп";
        }
        else
        {
            timerControl.StopTimer();
            btn_timerStart.Text = "Старт";
            
            
        }
    }

    private  void StopWatchTimer(object label)
    {
        Label timeLabel = (Label)label;
        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - timerControl.StartTime;
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
        {
            timeLabel.Text = elapsed.ToString(@"ss\.ff");
        }));
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D298K.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should look at Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then you can do this: `var startTime = DateTime.Now; Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10.0)).Select(x => (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"ss\.ff")).ObserveOn(l_timer).Subscribe(x => timeLabel.Text);`